# Strange Ruby error with Net::HTTP.get

Tags: ruby, http

I have the following Ruby code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

include Net

$DEBUG = 1

print "Enter a GitHub username: "
username = gets

puts "Username = #{username}" if $DEBUG == 1

source = HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://github.com/api/v2/xml/user/show/#{username}"))

puts source if $DEBUG == 1
```

Whenever I run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception `Errno::EAGAIN' at /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135 - Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block
```

Even though it works fine. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to stop it happening?

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT*: Using [htty](https://github.com/htty/htty), I was able to connect to the desired server and get the resource just fine without any errors.

Comment: Your code worked for me as is, Ruby 1.8.7/Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that your use of the global `$DEBUG` variable is revealing a bug or undesired state in Net::Protocol. If you set `$DEBUG = false` it goes away.

At that point in the Net::Protocol code it's trying to do a non_blocking read, and appears to be timing out.

Ruby uses the $DEBUG flag as part of the `-d` mechanism. If you put `puts $DEBUG` in a script and run it you'll see that variable toggle. Because it's a global it'll be visible in any code needing debugging so you, or the code's author, can trigger extra-special verboseness to help debug things:

```
greg-mbp-wireless:Desktop greg$ ruby untitled.rb 
false
greg-mbp-wireless:Desktop greg$ ruby -d untitled.rb 
true
```

Answer (score 1):

That's your $DEBUG = 1, if $DEBUG is not defined (or set to false) there are no errors.  Probably Ruby interpreter uses this internally and if it's set it prints out debug info.